# UI to personalize a vimrc without writing one from scratch

Tags: vimrc, options

Vim is so infinitely configurable.  However, devising a vimrc is a daunting task for novices and intermediate users.  Basically, you're expected to develop one from a blank slate by reading the documentation and picking up serendipitous tips from other users.

Is there an intuitive configuration menu to help beginners generate and revise a vimrc?  Maybe a web-based tool, or something analogous to an options dialog in a word processor?

[image: LibreOffice preferences screenshot (CC-BY-SA 3.0 from th.libreoffice.org/get-help/installation/mac/)]

Answer (score 14):

You can use the built-in `:options` and `:mkvimrc` (see `:help :options` and `:help :mkvimrc`).

But… creating your own `~/.vimrc` is a daunting task *only* if you want the perfect `vimrc` "right now". If you are not patient enough, there are dozens of alternative editors with less options and GUI dialogs. Vim is not an editor you can pick up in an afternoon: expect work and reading.

Comment: Exactly this. I've been using Vim for 8 years and I'm still writing my vimrc. If you try to configure too much at once, you won't remember what you've done and you'll forget to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 13):

One website for generating `.vimrc`s is http://vimconfig.com/ .  It's fairly basic — just enough to get started on  (line numbers, search highlighting, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: this answer is obviously wrong as other answers link to the tools.
However, this reply might have same value as to the alternate (maybe even better) approach to the root problem thread author has.

Unfortunately I don't think such a tool exists.

But to answer the "root" of your question - you definitely don't have to start writing your `.vimrc` from scratch. Common practice among beginning users is to look into `.vimrc` files of expert vim users. Here are some examples you could learn a lot from:

- [Tim Pope's vimrc](https://github.com/tpope/tpope/blob/master/.vimrc) - creator of many ingenious vim plugins
- [Drew Neil's vimrc](https://github.com/nelstrom/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc) - author of vimcasts.org
- [Gary Bernhard's vimrc](https://github.com/garybernhardt/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) - creator of destroyallsoftware.com and a well known vim user
- [Steve Losh's vimrc](https://bitbucket.org/sjl/dotfiles/src/603bb1ae9da27c6e08ab115df1cb5d8f6a1442c3/vim/vimrc?at=default) - the author of popular VimL book and a couple popular plugins

Lastly, there's Tim Pope's plugin [vim-sensible](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible) that provides some fundamentals and I'd recommend installing it.